# No traffic when listening with netcat

Tags: linux, tcpdump, netcat

I have a server with multiple network interfaces.
I'm trying to run a network monitoring tools in order to verify network traffic statistics by using the sFlow standard on a router.
I get my sFlow datagram on port 5600 of eth1 interface. I'm able to see the generated traffic thanks to tcpdump:

```
user@lnssrv:~$ sudo tcpdump -i eth1

14:09:01.856499 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1456
14:09:02.047778 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1432
14:09:02.230895 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1300
14:09:02.340114 IP 198.51.100.253.5678 > 255.255.255.255.5678: UDP, length 111
14:09:02.385036 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id c01e.b4:a4:e3:0b:a6:00.8018, length 43
14:09:02.434658 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1392
14:09:02.634447 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1440
14:09:02.836015 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1364
14:09:03.059851 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1372
14:09:03.279067 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1356
14:09:03.518385 IP 10.10.10.10.60147 > 198.51.100.232.5600: UDP, length 1440
```

It seems all ok, but, when i try to read the packet with netcat it seems that there are no packets here:

```
nc -lu 5600
```

Indeed, sflowtool nor nprobe doesn't read anything from port 5600.
Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`nc -lu 5600` is going to open a socket on port `5600`, meaning that it will only dump packages that are received in that socket, i.e, packages aiming to that specific address and port.

On the other side, tcpdump collects all the traffic flowing, even without it being sent to a specific server.

Two causes of your problem here:

**a)** Your host IP is not `198.51.100.232`

- With **`host`** command you will be able exactly see TCP traffic of your server

  `for example : tcpdump -i eth1 host 198.51.100.232 port 80`

**b)** There is another server that is listening in UDP port `5600` that is grabbing all the data, so, nothing is leftover for nc socket.

- **Notice:** with **`TCPDUMP`** you will not be able to check and listen UDP ports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My host ip is 198.51.100.232, so I think this is not a cause of the problem. On the other side, when i try to list currently open udp socket with `netstat --listen` it show me that port 5600 is not bind to anything. But, when i try a test command: `echo -n "foo" | nc -4u 198.51.100.232 5600` my netcat device retrieves the packet...

Comment: Hmm, can you try the same with lsof? I don't  believe in netstat too much.

lsof -i UDP:5600

Comment: `lsof -i udp` returns an empty string...also `lsof -i | grep 5600` returns nothing...

Comment: I think that for some reason netstat and lsof listen to the wrong network interface...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it can help here but in my case it helped ( I had similar problem ) so i just stopped "iptables" like
service iptables stop.
It seems that tcpdump works on the lower level than iptable and ipdaple can stop datagrams from being proceed to the higher level. Here a good [article](https://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) on this topic with [nice picture](https://www.brendangregg.com/Perf/linux_perf_tools_full.png).